# Is there any option to change the videoplayer in kivy?

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy

I have a project that is built with kivy. It has one video background, one video that is over the background and the third layer of text. It works fine on windows, but when I run it on raspberry pi 4 4gb the videos are playing with 5fps.
I want to change the kivy video player(gstream) with something else.  I wish i was playing it with omxplayer inside of kivy, so I have the control over the second video size and position.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry I can't make a comment yet, but I did kind of a similar integration and I managed to use omxplayer by following this guys blog. Hope that helps

https://www.codedesigner.de/articles/omxplayer-kivy-overlay/

Comment: Thank you for your response, but I already found the blog and I installed https://pypi.org/project/omxplayer-wrapper/. The thing is that when i overlay the videos the work on the same process and background stops and the foreground plays and then the background stops. I will try to make it with 2 processes of OMXPlayer inside kivy, because i want those two processes work on different cores, or independently and overlay text over both.